# Can't set up witness in Repmgr 2.0

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, failover, repmgr

I am trying to setup repmgr using the autofailover quick setup tutorial provided on Github [Link](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/repmgr/blob/master/autofailover_quick_setup.rst)

But I am kind of stuck on the witness section, when trying to create the witness with `repmgr -d repmgr -U repmgr -h [MASTERIP] -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/witness -f /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/repmgr/repmgr.conf witness create`

I get the following error:

`Connection to database failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

I am not sure which database the error is talking about? Is it the master's DB or the witness'?

Also, I haven't been able to find a password parameter to pass to repmgr yet, is there even one?

Below are the repmgr.conf files for each server:

Witness:

```
cluster=main
node=3
node_name=witness
conninfo='host=[WITNESS IP] dbname=witness user=witness password=witness  port=5499'
master_response_timeout=60
reconnect_attempts=6
reconnect_interval=10
failover=automatic
promote_command='promote_command.sh'
follow_command='/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/repmgr standby follow -f /etc/repmgr/repmgr.conf'
```

Standby:

```
cluster=main
node=2
node_name=node2
conninfo='host=[STANDBY IP] dbname=[DB NAME] user=[DB USER NAME] password=[PASSWORD]'
master_response_timeout=60
reconnect_attempts=6
reconnect_interval=10
failover=automatic
promote_command='promote_command.sh'
follow_command='/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/repmgr standby follow -f /etc/repmgr/repmgr.conf'
```

Master:

```
cluster=main
node=1
node_name=node1
conninfo='host=[MASTER IP] dbname=[MASTER DB] user=[MASTER DB USER] password=[PASSWORD]'
master_response_timeout=60
reconnect_attempts=6
reconnect_interval=10
failover=automatic
promote_command='promote_command.sh'
follow_command='/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/repmgr standby follow -f /etc/repmgr/repmgr.conf'
```

Comment: Interesting issue. Looks like we could make some improvements to error reporting there. repmgr version?

Comment: Sorry completely forgot to delete the post on SO I have deleted it now though. To answer your other question the version is 2.0beta1 from the repmgr website

Comment: Appreciated. Re passwords have you tried using a .pgpass file (see pg docs) instead of trying to specify passwords in the conninfo strings?

Comment: did you ever get a solution for this? Facing the same problem here....

Comment: any solutions? got the same

Comment: No, sorry. I ended up using a different solution if I remember correctly. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

The error message means that `repmgr` account can't login onto **master** server with provided password (probably empty one).

You need to allow connections on **master**, in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host    all     repmgr  192.168.1.1/32       md5
host    replication     all     192.168.1.1/32       md5
```

then trigger a master server reload:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl reload -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main
```

(where `-D` is the data directory of PostgreSQL).

Assumsing you've created a `repmgr` account, on master with some `secret_passw0rd`

```
createuser --login --superuser -P repmgr -W
createdb -O repmgr repmgr
```

then on **standby** server create a `.pgpass` file in `postgres` home:

```
su - postgres
cat > .pgpass << EOF
*:*:*:repmgr:secret_passw0rd
EOF
chmod 0600 .pgpass
```

That's all under assumption that you're using `md5` password authentication for replication, if you switch to `trust` you could skip setting the password:

```
host    all     repmgr  192.168.1.1/32       trust
host    replication     all     192.168.1.1/32       trust
```

Now you can check connection to your master server:

```
psql -h master.hostname -U repmgr
```